# Accessing Flow Loop Variables in Custom Property Editors

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I having been trying out Custom Property Editors for Flow as outlined [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-flow-custom-property-editor-action-example.html).
For the most part, with some trial and error, I have gotten it to work, with one notable exception:

In a Flow Loop, it now automatically generates a Loop Variable you can reference:
[image]

But in the custom property editor, I can't find a way to reference it?
[image]

I looked at the Loop Flow Metadata that gets sent to the LWC, but the old manual variable you used to use is null, and I don't see it in the metadata?

```
"loops": [
    {
      "name": "Test_Loop",
      "description": "",
      "label": "Test Loop",
      "locationX": 176,
      "locationY": 242,
      "nextValueConnector": {
        "targetReference": "Set_curPlace"
      },
      "assignNextValueToReference": null,
      "collectionReference": "varCollection1",
      "iterationOrder": "Asc"
    }
  ],
```

As a workaround, I can do an assignment in the loop to a local variable (e.g. the currPlace2 variable in the first image), and then use that, but that is going to be a bit confusing for an admin\and is really a regression from Summer 20.
Is there someplace else I should be looking for that variable?

Comment: Looking at the metadata from a flow in my own org, it looks like the reference is actually the API name of the loop element itself (so in your case Test_Loop). I wonder if this could be used in your custom property editor? If that works it would mean having to look at both the variables and loops element of the metadata that is passed to your LWC so I'd be keen to see if that does work for you.

Comment: Ah, didn't make that connection, because the docs only talk about variables, but you are right - that totally works. Add as an answer, and I can mark as correct, and then add a follow up answer with how you combine variables with loop variables for the admin to select from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted above, the new automatically created variable for the loop can be accessed by referencing the API name of the Loop itself. To ensure that this is accessible in a Custom Property Editor, we need to create a list of options for admins to select that is a combination of the variables and loops elements supplied by the Flow to the LWC.

Something similar to the below should work:

```
get valueOptions() {
    const variables = this.builderContext.variables;
    const loops = this.builderContext.loops;
    let options = [];

    variables.forEach(variable => {
      options.push({label: name, value: name});
    });

    loops.forEach(loop => {
      options.push({label: 'Current Item for ' + loop.label, value: loop.name});
    });

    return options;
}
```

EDIT: As per comments (thanks sfdcfox and Phil W), a more modern approach to this would be:

```
get valueOptions() {
    return [...this.builderContext.variables.map(name => ({
        label: name,
        name
    })), ...this.builderContext.loops.map(({
        label,
        name
    }) => ({
        label: `Current Item for ${label}`,
        name
    }))];
}
```

Comment: Nice! Though... "var" is so last century! Let's use "const" where we can and "let" where we can't!

Comment: Valid, I need to get better at using them! I've updated it now thanks.

Comment: forEach/push is slower and longer (more source) than just using map. Here's a modern implementation: `get valueOptions() { return [ ...this.builderContext.variables.map(name => ({ label: name, name })), ...this.builderContext.loops.map(({ label, name }) => ({ label: \`Current Item for ${label}\`, name })) ]; }` I know this looks pretty illegible in a comment, but run it through a JS formatter, you'll see its beauty.

Comment: Thanks, that is a lot nicer. I've updated the answer with that too.